# Difference between recommended and suggested cookbooks

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

Not able to make clear difference between the suggested and recommended cookbook setting in chef. And when to use which setting.

Answer (score 4):

Currently the `suggests` and `recommends` keywords in the metadata file are equal in that neither of them has any effect.

The semantics of these keywords [been proposed](http://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-3870) however they have not been implemented as of Chef 11.